# How to parse this specific JSON?

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I'm trying to parse this JSON and I'm trying to get the "fields" bracket and access the symbol and the price. My apologies if this is a noob question, I honestly don't know how to parse this JSON because it seems as if you have to go really deep to get to the price and symbol. Thanks in advance.

Here's a link to the JSON if you need that: http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/aapl/quote?format=json

Here's the json:

```
{
"list" : { 
    "meta" : { 
        "type" : "resource-list",
        "start" : 0,
        "count" : 1
    },
    "resources" : [ 
    {
        "resource" : { 
            "classname" : "Quote",
            "fields" : { 
                "name" : "Apple Inc.",
                "price" : "100.529999",
                "symbol" : "AAPL",
                "ts" : "1456866001",
                "type" : "equity",
                "utctime" : "2016-03-01T21:00:01+0000",
                "volume" : "50075193"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

Code I have so far:

```
 let requestURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/aapl/quote?format=json")!
    let urlRequest: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
        let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            print("Everyone is fine, file downloaded successfully.")

            do{

                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)

                if let test = json["fields"]!!["price"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {

                } //end stations

            }catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")

                //end catch
            }

        } //end if status code == 200
    } //end task


task.resume()
```

Comment: The JSON was poorly displayed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, it assumes that `json` is the root dictionary

```
if let resources = json["list"]?["resources"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
  if let fields = resources[0]["resource"]?["fields"] as? [String:String], price = fields["price"], symbol = fields["symbol"] {
    print(symbol, price)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For "this specific JSON":

`objectName.list.resources[0].resource.fields.price`

`objectName.list.resources[0].resource.fields.symbol`

You could impliment a loop if your object contains more than one of these data sets.

If this JSON object was created by your script, look at building a more usable object so you dont have to go too "deep".

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to do this exactly the same as how Superman puts on his pants: one leg at a time. Sure the symbol and price are buried deep in the data, but so what? You just keep diving down, like peeling the skins off an onion, until you get where you want to go.

So, if `d` is the NSData that you got from the network:

```
let dict = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(d!, options:[])
let list = dict["list"] as! NSDictionary
let res = list["resources"] as! NSArray
let dict2 = res[0] as! NSDictionary
let res2 = dict2["resource"] as! NSDictionary
let fields = res2["fields"] as! NSDictionary
let symbol = fields["symbol"] as! String
let price = fields["price"] as! String
```